# В чем суть этого выражения на php?

Tags: php

Не могу найти в документации ответ, ткните носом пожалуйста или объясните.

В чем смысл использования такого выражения?

К примеру есть класс

```
class testClass 
{
        public $msg;

        public function test($msg){
           $this->msg = $msg
        } 
}
```

Что происходит при обращении к самому классу вот так?

```
echo testClass::class;
print_r(testClass::class)
var_dump(testClass::class);
```

Во всех случаях возвращается строка testClass, при чем она возвращается даже есть класс не существует.

Comment: Вы и при таком описании класса `class testClass {}` получите всё тоже значение - __имя__ класса, т.к. оно содержится в константе `class` и ничего общего с вашим кодом в теле класса не имеет.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name

Comment: Можете сформулировать вопрос более конкретно, что вам непонятно. Если вы хотите обращаться к свойствам и методам тогда объявите класс $test = new testClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот простой пример:

```
<?php
namespace my\library\mvc;
class Dispatcher { }
print Dispatcher::class; // my\library\mvc\Dispatcher
```

Есть пространство имен "my\library\mvc", в нем класс Dispatcher, получим полный путь к классу соответственно: my\library\mvc\Dispatcher

Comment: Я не очень понимаю к чему ведет просто вызов ::class.

Я понимаю что через :: можно вызывать статические функции только для этого класса или внутри класса использовать self::

Но вызов ::class на самом классе нужно только для возврата его полного пути в пространстве имен?

Comment: @ИгорьТюлькин да, только для возврата полного пути, ::class - это константа, вы обращаетесь к ней, так же как и к статической переменной. Вот здесь можете почитать: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.constants.php